# Python package: Can I look for config/yml file from project directory which called it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, yaml, pypi

I am writing a Python package that contains a bunch of utility type functions that are specific to our team so they can install, import, and use them. Some of these functions access services that require authentication, so in the READ Me file, I have instructed them to create a YAML file in their project directory which houses their credentials.

When they import this package and call a function from it, is there a way for the package to look for this YAML file in the directory from which call it? Or do they need to parse the file themselves and pass the credentials as parameters into the function itself?

Comment: Just make sure you change to the directory the YAML file is in after you start the program, then the imported package can just look in the current directory. But on the other hand (on Linux, windows) there are standards for where to put your configuration files: https://pypi.org/project/xdg/, so why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__file__` variable contains the name or path the Python program. We can use functions from the `os.path` submodule to use this to get a file (in my example below called `password.yml`).

```
import os.path
prog = __file__
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(prog))
print(os.path.join(directory, 'password.yml'))
```

`abspath` converts the name to an absolute file (starting at the filesystem root). `dirname` removes the last (filename) component, leaving the directory, and `join` puts the directory path and the filename together using the appropriate separator for your platform (`'/'` for most operating systems, `'\'` for Windows).

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Happy to help. If it's solved your problem, please accept the answer. Points mean prizes! ;-)