# How to get the project `config/` directory from inside an installed Python package?

Tags: python, package, config

I have a Python database interface package, which requires configured credentials to work. I would like to tuck those away in a config file, that's not committed to the interface repository. So I have the following structure in mind:

```
my_project/
|-  config/
|   |-  database.json
|-  main.py                   (Contains 'from my_interface import Connection')
|-  ...
```

```
my_interface/
|-  src/
|   |-  module.py
|   |-  ...
|-  ...
```

**But how can I make `my_interface` find the config directory in the project that's importing it?**

The interface could be installed as system, or as user, or in a `venv` and it could be editable, so trying to navigate up from inside `module.py` (with `__file__`) cannot be reliable.

I found a bunch of similar questions, but they don't seem to tackle how to approach this from inside an imported package, instead relying on `__file__`:

- [Python package: Can I look for config/yml file from project directory which called it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52994289/python-package-can-i-look-for-config-yml-file-from-project-directory-which-call)
- [Python - Get path of root project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389095/python-get-path-of-root-project-structure)

Comment: Why not load the config in `main.py` and pass argument to the functions in `my_interface`? If `my_interface` should handle the file let `main.py` resolve the filepath and pass that.

Comment: That is a fair point. The main consideration is that all users would have to make their own config locating bit, which I would rather avoid.

Comment: Two more ideas apart from relative to `main.py`: use environment variables or have a `my_interface_config.py` that is importable (CWD, `PYTHONPATH`, `sys.path.append()`). Using a lib usually means collecting needed parameters. Maybe the user wants to handle the config differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can read environment variable
`CONFIG_PATH = os.getenv('CONFIG_PATH', '<standart-path-to-config>')` in **module.py**
You can change this variable in **main.py** or somewhere else